# control the output file at binary level

Tags: pdf

I would like to generate a PDF file via PDFTeX that is also a Windows Executable at the same time (the resulting file is a [polyglot](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/mix?show=content)).

For this, I need the PDF file, among other thing, to start with the 'MZ' letters.

Can I do that via a specific macro or package?

Comment: What's a “Windows executable polyglot”? Can you give a reference?

Comment: @egreg edited with clarification

Comment: [OMG WTF PDF](http://www.the-digital-reader.com/2011/01/02/27c3-omg-wtf-pdf/). :-{

Comment: @MartinSchröder (my page on the topic)[pdf.corkami.com]. I also made a bootable PDF (PoC||GTFO 0x02).

Answer (score 9):

Your "polyglot" is not a valid PDF file. A canonical PDF file starts with the PDF header (`%PDF-1.x`). However Acrobat Reader and some other PDF viewers are less strict, from the implementation notes in the PDF specification:

> **3.4.1, "File Header"**
>   13. Acrobat viewers require only that the header appear somewhere within
>       the first 1024 bytes of the file.

A canonical PDF file ends with `%%EOF` in the last line. Again, Acrobat Reader is less strict:

> **3.4.4, "File Trailer"**
>   18. Acrobat viewers require only that the `%%EOF` marker appear somewhere
>         within the last 1024 bytes of the file.

Thus there is some room to add a wrapper for other formats.

However, you cannot add something at the beginning or the end with pdfTeX.
But something can be added inside the PDF file:

```
\begingroup
  \pdfcompresslevel=0\relax
  \immediate\pdfobj stream file{foo.bar}\relax
\endgroup
```

Then the contents of file `foo.bar` can be found uncompressed inside the PDF file.

Comment: It is a valid file from my (malware analyst) perspective: it's rendered as expected, without any errors, by all readers (linux ones, sumatra, firefox, chrome, adobe).